# Extremely high TTFB when connecting to Oracle DB 11 via ODP.net

Tags: asp.net, oracle, get, web, odp.net

After mutiple days of searching Google, I still have the following issue:

1. I have an internal website, which is hosted on Win2012 server, and uses ODP.NET to connect to an oracle db.
2. The issue is that no matter what i do, no matter the IIS configuration or server load, the TTFB for loading ceratain pages is huge - more than 20s.
3. When the same site is hosted on a different host (test enviroment), the TTFB is <1s.
4. System setup - the productive server is win2012 server, the test sever is identical. Identical - same OS, same patch level ,same services, same setup. 
   Both machines are virtual, with the productive having 24GB RAM and 2xXeon 2.2Ghz
5. So far i have conducted the following test - changed the oracle host in tnsnames to the host IP - no effect. Stopped all services running on the server - no effect. System load does not at any time exceed 50% CPU time , 45% memory, 4Mbps / out of a 2x100Mbps. Disk I/O operations are acceptable - no more than 5MB/s at a maximum. ODP.NET trace shows gaps of
6. Slight improvement was noticed when the number of worker processes was increated from 1 do 3 , but he web site requires a repeat of the log on after the server changes the WP which currently handles the user.
   In short- from server A the site loads a page for 25-30s, from server B (identical) the page loads in 1-2s.

My request is : would you please recommend where should i am my efforts, or is there a windows based tool which would allow me to break down the TTFB to a more detailed view than the one offered by chrome/IE.
Thank you kindly for your responses.

Comment: Seems to me there's an excellent chance this is really a question for [SF].

Comment: You should define "TTFB" on first use - that's the first I have heard of it after 20 years of being in computing.

Answer (score 1):

Start by enabling logging and see if there is anything that stands out:

```
<configuration>
 <oracle.dataaccess.client>
   <add key="TraceFileName" value="c:\temp\odpnet1.trc"/>
   <add key="TraceLevel" value="63"/>
   <add key="TraceOption" value="0"/>
 </oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

The "certain pages" part throws me off a bit.  Your test server is connected to the same database, yes?  The test server consistently has better performance?  In other words, you are sure this isn't related to query performance?  Does the test server go thru the same networks to get to the server (tracert oracleserver)?

Comment: ODP.NET trace was ran and showed several gaps, for example :                                                                                TIME:2015/03/16-13:56:49:881 TID: 948  (POOL)  Total number of connections for pool (id: -1090673252) : 6
TIME:2015/03/16-13:56:55:294 TID:1364  (ENTRY) OpsGetAvailPhysMemory()   and also  :                                  TIME:2015/03/16-13:59:58:210 TID:1da0  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1357
TIME:2015/03/16-14:00:15:963 TID:1260  (REGISTRY) (CheckConStatus : 1). The test server exhibits much lower TTFB, running the same queries

Comment: over the same network infrastructure (both servers are part of a corporate intranet)

Comment: Can you also post a  complete section of the log as an attachment?  You can change server names if you want to but I'd like to see more of it.  Looking at those times though it definitely looks like you have some gaps.  Can you also post your connection string and tnsnames entry (again, it's fine to replace server names or anything else you see as specific).